# Win 7 defragmenter doesn't show all partitions

Tags: windows-7, defragment

I just discovered yesterday that my D: partition isn't showing up in the Windows 7 defragmenter.

All my other partitions (C, E, F) are there.

The D: partition is running and working just fine - heck I've even got my users folder there, so the desktop and so forth are on it.

Any clues what might cause this ?

Comment: You could try an alternative defragmenter, such as defragler.

Comment: True I could, however I'm rather certain the partition being missing is just a symptom of something else. And it's the "something else" I want to fix :-D

Comment: You should upgrade to third party defragmentation software, the windows 7 in-built is good but it is also limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force a `CHKDSK` on that partition and reboot. It may have a dirty bit set and needs to run a scan to make sure defrag is safe.

Comment: chkdsk -R did it :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it!